# code inside angular subscribe not waiting for API response to come

Tags: angular, observable

Code inside angular subscribe not waiting for API response to complete? Is it waiting for only API response status code not the actual response value?

I have an API which generally gives RSA public key (string) in response. I am calling the API from Angular (version 8) ts file.

```js
//For fetching public key from API response 
    this.authService.publicKeyGen(identifier).subscribe(
            res => {
              console.log("fooooo...");   NOT PRINTING / NOT EXECUTING
              pubKey = res;
            },
              (e => console.log('error: ', e)),
              (() => console.log('the sequence completed!'))  PRINTING / EXECUTING
            );

    public publicKeyGen(identifier) {
        let url = this.authUrl + "/v1/keys/generate";
        return this.http.get(url, {
          params: { identifier : identifier}
        });
      }
```

Though the API call is success (status code 200) but it is not going inside the "res" and I am not able to get the response value.

**Note**: Actually the API returns success code 200 first and then after a small delay it is giving the response data. Inside the subscribe, I am not able to set the public key from response value as API call gets success (200) but the API response data still not available and not executing the "res" part though it is going inside the subscribe as API status code already came.

Please help.

API Response -
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDTqMCDom4QjKFoucN/Wa5CJ+eECcs2Q7V5uAWH4DUc1F3+02LsWOwWP5JKVLKOEBjybR50eKpGLsTwnIUNeh8oRsq7l4YAaeYDSrbkij62m8tsPyMwleeD3jIc8RlAD7Zt/bTvJGMA/W6hJJ0wf0kU2pmPuauGBIdeZqoYhRNCqwIDAQAB

Comment: Probably due to the fact that the call is not returning JSON, may be the issue. Use httpClient.request and set the response type.

Comment: Yes it is string not json...will check it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the responseType for headers to verify it's response type from server.

```
 public publicKeyGen(identifier) {
    let url = this.authUrl + "/v1/keys/generate";
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'text/plain'); 
    return this.http.get(url, { headers, responseType: 'text'});
 }
```

If it's plain string then console log will print. You can convert it to JSON by using parse method like below

```
const pubKey = JSON.parse(res);
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Hi Ganesh,
Thanks for replying. The header part inside get() is throwing me compilation error.
"Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3"

Comment: Hi Ganesh...thanks for helping me out. After adding {responseType: 'text'} it is accepting String response now.

I did like this in Angular 8 :
let httpOptions = {
      params: {'identifier' : identifier},
      responseType: 'text' as 'json'
    };
    return this.http.get(url, httpOptions);

Answer (score 1):

Is your `publicKeyGen` method reside in `auth.service.ts` file?

Also, better to add the return value to `publicKeyGen` signature, like so:

```
public publicKeyGen(identifier): Observable<string> {
    let url = this.authUrl + "/v1/keys/generate";
    return this.http.get(url, {
      params: { identifier : identifier}
    });
  }
```

Comment: Is your publicKeyGen method reside in auth.service.ts file? - Yes

Comment: I am not able to add return value Observable<String>. Getting this error.

Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'.
  Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

Comment: I tried to make return type String but still the same issue I am facing. It is not going inside subscribe response.